# How to plot a stacked column graph in R?

Tags: r, bar-chart

does anyone know how to use R to plot a histogram with the columns stacked up by more than 1 variables? Like the "stacked column" graph in excel.

Thank you!

Comment: Downvote: No evidence of searching in SO. No code.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you really want a bar chart rather than a histogram. In that case, `barplot` from standard graphics or `barchart` from the lattice package will both do it. Or use ggplot as shown in [this example](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/position_stack.html) or [here](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/ggplot2-barplots/)

Answer (score 4):

For example;

```
ht1=c(0.3,0.7)
ht2=c(0.4,0.6)
barplot(cbind(ht1,ht2))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also `barplot.xts` in the `xtsExtra` package.