# Barplot in R - How to divide the plot into separate parts by showing them in different colors

Tags: r

I am a newbie to R. I would like to create a barplot which is visually divided into different parts.

My data looks like the following:

```
"1.0";"0.0";"1.0";"2.0";"710";"12500"
```

first four numbers give the number of parts that need to be ordered from the two parts list below. The fifth number gives the result sum of the first part, the sixth then the result sum of the second part.

```
part 1: 10;50;100;300
part 2: 500;1000;2000;5000;
```

this is how it is calculated.

```
1 * 10 + 0 * 50 + 1 * 100 + 2 * 300 = 710 ;
1 * 500 + 0 * 1000 + 1 * 2000 + 2 * 5000 = 12500
```

So what I now want to plot is for example the value 12500, but I want to visually divide this value into the different part (stacked bars) like two five thousands, then one two thousand then one five hundred -> the bar should consist of these parts which can visually be seen or marked with the value (would be nice to have different colors for each part in the part)

How can I do it? Folks, I did my homework, I searched a lot and did try it on my own, but couldn't achieve what I want.

Comment: Is it the data organisation or the plotting that's giving you trouble?  If the latter, plotting stacked bar charts is dealt with in this [other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431657/how-to-plot-a-stacked-column-graph-in-r).

Comment: I would say the plotting because I already have an array of array containing the values so the data organisaton is ready I think, it may be inappropriate for plotting but I could do the muliplication.

Comment: If your data is in a data frame `d` with columns `vm1, ..., vm4`, then you'll get what you want by doing `barplot(t(as.matrix(d)))`.  The matrix transpose there is just to get the rows and columns the right way round for the barplot function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
daten <- matrix(c(10,50,100,300,500,1000,2000,5000),ncol=2) 
multiplier <- c(1,0,1,2)
barplot(daten*multiplier)
```

To display bar segments in reverse order, you need to rearrange the rows in the `daten*multiplier` array:

```
barplot((daten*multiplier)[nrow(daten):1,])
```

Comment: Thanks mzuba, now it is plotting as I wanted. But there is one more thing. How can I plot your example in the reverse order? Like what gets stacked on top of it should be the first one at the bottom etc? Like it  is plotted like 1->2->3->4 as stack but I want it 4->3->2->1 in this order